# how do i get collections which are in documents firestore into a list

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble in getting all collections from Cloud Firestore into a list of documents. Again I'm saying collections from document(documents -> collections) , not documents from collection(collections -> documents)
collections -> documents -> collections

```
db.collection("typesOfRepairs").document("Vehicles").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                Log.e("res",""+documentSnapshot.getData());
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                Log.e("res",""+e.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBLyr.png)

I know I will {Cars=2, Bikes=1} , but i need to get the collections(bikes,cars).

Comment: Please see the duplicate. To get the data within the subcollections, you need to creae separate queries.

Comment: You can not use nested query to retrieve such data. I suggest to use Recyclerview to retrieve specific Data.

Comment: @Ashish yes i need , but how to ,any example would help me a lot .